# Specific Row Values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can one ask Excel to record the value of all cells in a given column such that the row number is of the form row = 2^i for i in 1 to 100?  Would this necessarily use VBA?

Comment: Do you mean sum all the values where the row is in the series 2^i? 2,4,8,16, etc?

Comment: @Raystafarian Not quite.  I'd like the values of those cells to be placed in, say, B1,B2,B3...Bn. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following formula into cell B1 and drag down.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&2^(ROW(A1)))
```

Bear in mind, this will give you a **#REF!** error from row 21 onwards, as per Mike Fitzpatrick's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to take the sum of values in a row, say from `A1:Ax` where `x = 2^i`. You can do that without VBA using the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&(2^i)))
```

So substituting i=8 in the above formula will give you the sum of the first 8 rows in column A. The formula can easily be extended to account for ranges starting at other rows.

As far as I'm aware, Excel only supports 2^20 (1048576) rows.